# Awk - capturing errors in cp command

Tags: linux, unix, awk

We are using the below `awk` command in a shell script to distribute files from a given input file to four sub folders of a given destination directory.

```
awk -v dir=$base_dir -v p_num=$2 -v node=$3 -F '::' 'NR%p_num==node {print dir $1}' $input_file | xargs -P 6 -I {} cp {} $destination_directory/$node/
```

This is working fine, but not able to capture errors while running `cp`. 
How can I capture errors, especially `file not found`-errors from `cp`?

Sample of `input_file`:

```
/data/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/file1::2334::5667::2014-09-08
/data/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/file2::4454::5667::2014-09-09
/data/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/file3::9895::4445::2014-09-10
/data/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/file4::3674::5667::2014-09-18
```

How can I capture if any entry in the above file is missing or non-existing and causes `cp` to fail?

Comment: Crystal ball? There's no way for a tool to know if you intended it's input file to contain more entries than it does.

Comment: Hmm I am more interested in capturing errors of cp command...

Comment: I really don't get the point, if the source (or dest) is non existent you'll get an error from cp on stderr... if you want to catch it you may suffix with || <command if cp fail> or redirect the stderr output like 2>&1 >> output.log